# Flickering animation in bl

Tags: modeling, animation

I have interior scene in cycles render and it's flickering after rendering.
I denoised render with compositing nodes.
Rendered with Optix, GeForce RTX 2060, 200 samples, 24fps.

There is lighting (sun lamp 20W, portals, spotlights), plus hdri with strength of 15
[image: lighting]

See flickering animation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dqozCEtRvSE

Comment: It's likely caused by denoising. Try disabling it or increasing the number of samples

Answer (score 0):

This flickering looks like the typical denoise smears (flickering). It can be that your denoising way too much/strong, so the smears of the denoise changes from frame to frame and are not consistent anymore because your raw output is too noisy.
You can try to set a denoise seed or you might need to render with more samples. You can also try to denoise the animation afterwards, in a other program.